# Pairwise comparisons within the same column in R

Tags: r, dataframe, tidyverse, data-manipulation

I have certain response variable (biomass) that I am analyzing across a series of environmental conditions that were retrieved from different papers.

Example dataset:

| Paper | Biomass | Condition |
| --- | --- | --- |
| P1 | 10 | Control |
| P1 | 5 | Species1 |
| P1 | 0 | Species1 |
| P2 | 2 | Control |
| P2 | 4 | Species4 |
| P2 | 6 | Species4 |
| P3 | 2 | Control |
| P3 | 2 | Species1 |
| P3 | 8 | Species2 |
| P3 | 6 | Species3 |
| P3 | 7 | Species4 |
| P3 | 2 | Species5 |
| P4 | 3 | Control |
| P4 | 1 | Species6 |

For each paper, I want to divide the biomass results of each species for the control specifically. For example, for P1 (paper 1), I want to divide (/) the biomass results of each species for the control.

Example output (I used random numeric results here):

| Paper | Comparison | Biomass_results |
| --- | --- | --- |
| P1 | Control vs Species1 | 5 |
| P2 | Control vs Species4 | 4 |
| P3 | Control vs Species1 | 2 |
| P3 | Control vs Species2 | 6 |
| P3 | Control vs Species3 | 7 |
| P3 | Control vs Species4 | 3 |
| P3 | Control vs Species5 | 2 |
| P4 | Control vs Species6 | 1 |

Any suggestions?

I tried to use tidyverse but with no success.

Comment: What do you mean by "divide results"? Can you please add an expected output via edit?

Comment: Just edited. Hope it is clear now.

Comment: How should your result look like? Provide an answer (data frame) that should be created from your input.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

This might give the expected results.

First `sum` the *Species*, then construct the *Comparison* strings, finally do the division and `filter` the end result.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  summarize(Biomass_sum = sum(Biomass), .by = c(Paper, Condition)) %>% 
  mutate(Comparison = paste("Control vs", Condition),
         Biomass_results = Biomass_sum / 
           Biomass_sum[Comparison == "Control vs Control"], .by = Paper) %>% 
  filter(Comparison != "Control vs Control") %>% 
  select(-c(Biomass_sum, Condition))
  Paper          Comparison Biomass_results
1    P1 Control vs Species1       0.5000000
2    P2 Control vs Species4       5.0000000
3    P3 Control vs Species1       1.0000000
4    P3 Control vs Species2       4.0000000
5    P3 Control vs Species3       3.0000000
6    P3 Control vs Species4       3.5000000
7    P3 Control vs Species5       1.0000000
8    P4 Control vs Species6       0.3333333
```

##### Data

```
df <- structure(list(Paper = c("P1", "P1", "P1", "P2", "P2", "P2", 
"P3", "P3", "P3", "P3", "P3", "P3", "P4", "P4"), Biomass = c(10L, 
5L, 0L, 2L, 4L, 6L, 2L, 2L, 8L, 6L, 7L, 2L, 3L, 1L), Condition = c("Control", 
"Species1", "Species1", "Control", "Species4", "Species4", "Control", 
"Species1", "Species2", "Species3", "Species4", "Species5", "Control", 
"Species6")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -14L))
```